# Execute postgres stored procedures in AWS AURORA write instance

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have AWS aurora DB (POSTGRES ENGINE) with write and read replicas defined. In my nodeJS application I am using sequelize to connect to aurora DB. My sequelize connections is like:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
dialect: 'postgres',
replication: {
  read: [
    readdbCreds
  ],
  write: writedbCreds
},
logging: false,
pool :{
    max: 50,
    min: 0
} })
```

So by default any SELECT query goes to read replica and UPDATE goes to WRITE replica. The problem I am facing is with stored procedures. I am executing stored procedures as:

```
sequelize.query(`call sp_name()`);
```

My stored procedures are getting executed in read replicas. I want them to get executed in WRITE instance as I have CREATE TABLE queries in it.